# android synchronized method does not work as expected

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, synchronized

so i have a class that contains an arrayList of items to be rendered on screen, using Opengl ES 2.0.

i have a method which goes through the list, and draws it on screen,

```
@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl10) {
  drawItems();
}

public static final Object mutex = new Object();

drawItems(){
 synchronized(mutex){
   for (Item item : mItemList){
     drawItem(item);
   }
 }
}
```

and on the class which contain the list:

```
class ItemListClass{

  private ArrayList<Item> mList;
  ...

  public void addItem(Item item){
    synchronized(Renderer.mutex){
       mList.add(item);
     }
 }
 public void removeItem(int pos){
    synchronized(Renderer.mutex){
      mList.remove(pos);
    }
 }
```

now, i still get a java.util.ConcurrentModificationException.

am i misunderstanding the use of the synchronized keyword? or what am i missing here?

Comment: `ConcurrentModificationException` can be thrown if you're mutating a `List` whilst iterating over that list, regardless of threading - ref : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html . As for a synchronised `List` consider a `CopyOnWriteArrayList` instead of `synchronised` blocks - this is a far easier way to maintain a synchronised `List`.

Comment: yeah, but i thought that since the for loop is inside the synchronized scope, it will work.. i am familiar with CopyOnwriteArrayList, i just don't understand why this code doesn't work..

Comment: what does `drawItem(item);` do?  Also your `ArrayList` should be a `volatile` variable.  either way you are either, somehow modifying the collection on 2+ threads, or mutating whilst iterating over the list somewhere in your code - maybe the supplied code isn't the complete `List` touch points?

Comment: @ariel t There was a similar problem with modifying the list in the render loop, for the solution I also used the CopyOnWriteArrayList collection.

Comment: @MarkKeen upon reviewing the code again, there was a place i used to clear the list, where i didn't add to the synchronized block.. i did it and thus far i haven't experienced another exception... i hope this was it, seems to be difficult to debug these issues, it was not simple to duplicate the error before i made the change